# Я не понимаю как в Listbox добавить текст при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
 
spisok = ['Черкаси', 'Чернігів', 'Чернівці']

win = Tk()

frame = Frame(win)
 
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)

scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
 
listbox = Listbox(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=40)
 
def knopka():

    listbox.insert(i)
 
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

btn = Button(win, text='Нажми на меня', command=knopka)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1) Для начала убедитесь, что отступы в коде , что я был вынужден исправить, верные. `knopka` - из одной строки? 2) Что конкретно вы не понимаете? Укажите конкретную проблему. Например, "вот документация, эта фраза непонятна".

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

spisok = ['Черкаси', 'Чернігів', 'Чернівці']

win = Tk()

frame = Frame(win)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, width=40)

def knopka():
    listbox.insert(0,*spisok)

listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

btn = Button(win, text='Нажми на меня', command=knopka)
btn.pack()

win.mainloop()
```